# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in my react project which I'm connecting to Elasticsearch.

Link to my code:
[codesandbox.io/s/oq13r4vl2q](http://codesandbox.io/s/oq13r4vl2q)

I'm trying to display result which I get from running the query in react for Elasticsearch but I'm unable to do that. It's giving error but when I am running the same query in a variable it returning the currect result. Can someone please tell me how to store the result in the "results" array and how to display that in the webpage?
Getting error on this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import client from './Credentials';
import '../App.css';
import DisplayResult from './DisplayResult';
export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {results: []};
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const search_query = event.target.value;

        client.search({
            index: 'tweet',
            type: 'tweet',
            size: 100,
            body: {
                query: {
                    match: search_query
                },
            }
        }, function (error, response, status) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("search error: " + error)
            }
            else {
                console.log("--- Response ---");
                // console.log(response);
                console.log("--- Hits ---");
                response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
                        console.log(hit._source.text);
                        this.setState(results: hit._source.text)
                    }.bind(this)

                )
            }
        });
    }




    render() {

        return(

            <div>
                <input className={"search-bar"} type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                </input>
                <DisplayResult results={this.state.results} />
                {/*<button className={"button"}><Search /></button>*/}

            </div>

        );

    }

}
```

Comment: what line is the error happening on?

Comment: response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
                            console.log(hit._source.text);
                            this.setState(results: hit._source.text)
                        }.bind(this)

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're losing the context of `this`. You can either format your code like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import client from './Credentials';
import '../App.css';
import DisplayResult from './DisplayResult';
export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {results: []};
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let _this = this;
        const search_query = event.target.value;

        client.search({
            index: 'tweet',
            type: 'tweet',
            size: 100,
            body: {
                query: {
                    match: search_query
                },
            }
        }, function (error, response, status) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("search error: " + error)
            }
            else {
                console.log("--- Response ---");
                // console.log(response);
                console.log("--- Hits ---");
                response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
                        console.log(hit._source.text);
                        _this.setState(results: hit._source.text)
                    }.bind(this)

                )
            }
        });
    }
```

**OR**

You can just use fat arrow functions to pick up the lexical binding of `this` (my recommendation).

All you have to do is change

```
 function (error, response, status) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("search error: " + error)
            }
            else {
                console.log("--- Response ---");
                // console.log(response);
                console.log("--- Hits ---");
                response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
                        console.log(hit._source.text);
                        _this.setState(results: hit._source.text)
                    }.bind(this)

                )
            }
        });
```

TO

```
 (error, response, status) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("search error: " + error)
            } else {
                console.log("--- Response ---");
                // console.log(response);
                console.log("--- Hits ---");
                response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
                        console.log(hit._source.text);
                        this.setState(results: hit._source.text)
                    });
            }
        });
```

Comment: While using the first solution it's giving bad request for client.search. I thin it is not taking the value of "search_query" in it.

Comment: Is the second solution giving you the same issue?

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/tweet/tweet/_search?size=100 400 (Bad Request)  Getting this from both the solution.

Comment: let result = client.search({
    index: 'tweet',
    type: 'tweet',
    size: 100,
    body: {
        query: {
            match: {"text" : "new" }
        },
    }
},function (error, response, status) {
    if (error){
        console.log("search error: "+error)
    }
    else {
        console.log("--- Response ---");
        // console.log(response);
        console.log("--- Hits ---");
        response.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit){
            console.log(hit._source.text);

        })
    }
});  is returning currect output but am using it in this then giving err

Comment: Is the original error you stated in your question solved?

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question with the issue that's now coming up.

Comment: Thanks, will do that